# Prove $e^{z+w}=e^ze^w$ using the Taylor expansion for $ e^z.$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, taylor-expansion

For all $z,w ∈ \Bbb{C}$, using the power series definition for $e^z$, prove $e^{z+w}=e^ze^w$.

Comment: Did you try this? Try this first for $z,w = 1$ (or some familiar values) then put the variable back.

Comment: I'm currently expanding the series and then expanding some polynomials to find a pattern.

Comment: That is the way to proceed, good. See if you can spot the pattern : see the binomial expansion of $(w+z)^n$ for a hint.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that!

Comment: You are welcome! Once you have figured things out, you can write an answer and call me to see if it is right.

Comment: I'm finding it easier to prove the statement from $e^ze^w$ to $e^{z+w}$ but not the other way around. Thoughts?

Comment: I will write an answer now.

Comment: I posted my answer if you're still curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with $e^{z+w}$, we have :
\begin{align}
e^{z+w} & = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z+w)^n}{n!} \\ & = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}k \frac{z^kw^{n-k}}{n!}
\end{align}

Here's the point : we now need to collect terms of the form $z^K$ for *fixed* $K$. This will involve a change of variable.

---

To see how we do this, we write all the terms of this summation down , breaking it for $n = 0,1,2,...$:

\begin{align}
n = 0 & : & \binom{0}{0} \frac{z^0w^0}{ 0!} \\
n=1 & : & \binom{1}{0} \frac {z^0w^1}{ 1!} , \binom{1}{1} \frac{z^1w^0}{1!} \\
&\vdots& \\
n = N &:& \binom N0 \frac{z^0w^N}{N!} , \binom N1\frac{z^1 w^{N-1}}{N!}, \ldots , \binom NN \frac{z^Nw^0}{N!}\\
&\vdots&
\end{align}

This is one way of summing the terms : take all the terms for *fixed* $n$, sum these, and then sum over all $n$.

Now, let us do something different : we don't fix $n$. We fix $\mathbf k$. Now, let us write down what terms in the summation have $k=0$:
$$
\binom{0}{0} \frac{z^0w^0}{0!} , \binom 10 \frac{z^0w^1}{1!} , \binom 20 \frac {z^0w^2}{2!} , \ldots
$$

for say $k=7$, the $n = 0 \to 6$ *will not contribute* because $\binom nk$ in that case is zero. So if we look at which terms have $k=7$ in the summation, we get :
$$
\binom{7}{7} \frac{z^7w^0}{0!} + \binom 87 \frac{z^7w^1}{1!} + \binom 97 \frac{z^7w^2}{2!} + ...
$$

Now, the point is this : initially, we fixed $n$, and summed over all $k$, then summed over all $n$. Now, we fix $k$,sum over all $n$ then over all $k$.

Basically, I am trying to say that the summations can be interchanged :
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{z^kw^{n-k}}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \color{green}{\sum_{n \geq k}} \binom {n}{k} \frac{z^kw^{n-k}}{n!}
$$

This is an inversion of question : first, we asked "Fix $n$, for which $k$ is the summation term non-zero?" for which the answer was $0 \leq k \leq n$. Now, we ask "fix $k$, for which $n$ is the summation term non-zero?" Now the answer should be clear : it is so only when $n\geq k$ (think about this yourself).

Now, we have fixed $k$. Note that this is equivalent to calculating the coefficient of $z^k$. We only need to sum over $n$. But as $k$ is fixed, so is $z^k$ and $k!$, these come out of the summation. So the rest of the answer follows.

---

So fixing $K$, look at the coefficient of $z^K$. for $n < K$ we have $\binom nK = 0$, so no coefficient. For $n \geq K$, the term becomes $\binom nK \frac{w^{n-K}}{n!}$ , which after simplifying the factorial becomes $\frac{w^{n-K}}{K!(n-K)!}$.

In short, once we sum over all $n$, the coefficient of $z^K$ is :
$$
\sum_{n \geq K} \frac{w^{n-K}}{K!(n-K)!} \overbrace{=}^{t = n-K} \frac 1{K!}\sum_{t=0}^\infty\frac{w^t}{t!} = \frac{e^w}{K!}
$$

So now, once we have collected all the terms :
$$
e^{z+w} = \sum_{K=0}^\infty \frac {e^w}{K!} z^K = e^w \sum_{K=0}^\infty \frac{z^K}{K!} = e^we^z
$$

as expected.

Comment: Very nice. Hats off to you sir.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a trick worth knowing : fixing the inner variable and seeing how the outer varies is a trick in both integration and summation theory.

Comment: Will definitely look more into that!

Comment: Great . Take your time and accept some answer so that the question can be closed. Furthermore, do continue to visit the website : you can also call me to questions if you like, using this page.

Comment: When $n\geq k$, what happens to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$?

Comment: I'm assuming you let n=K?

Comment: I will answer it, but right now I am not on my PC, so I request some time

Comment: No , that is not the case. I think I will elaborate, but I need some time. To be honest, I had forgotten the earlier request, so I will fulfill it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104353/discussion-between-----and-whitenoise).

Comment: @whitenoise you can check the answer now. Have I done justice?

Comment: Late reply, but thank you so much for your very detailed. This definitely does justice!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Proved it the following way:

**Claim:** $e^{z+w}=e^ze^w$, where $z\;and\;w\in \Bbb{C}$.

**Proof:**

Let $e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots$

and  $e^w=1+w+\frac{w^2}{2!}+\frac{w^3}{3!}+\cdots$ .

Now, for RHS:

$e^ze^w=\big(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\big)\big(1+w+\frac{w^2}{2!}+\frac{w^3}{3!}+\cdots\big)$

$=1+w+\frac{w^2}{2!}+\frac{w^2}{3!}+z+zw+\frac{zw^2}{2!}+\frac{zw^3}{3!}+\cdots$

$=1+(z+w)+(\frac{z^2}{2!}+zw+\frac{w^2}{2!})+(\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^2w}{2!}+\frac{zw^2}{2!}+\frac{w^2}{3!})\cdots$

$=1+(z+w)+(\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{2zw}{2!}+\frac{w^2}{2!})+(\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{3z^2w}{3!}+\frac{3zw^2}{3!}+\frac{w^2}{3!})\cdots$

$=1+(z+w)+\frac{(z+w)^2}{2!}+\frac{(z+w)^3}{3!}+\cdots$

$=e^{z+w} \;QED.$

Comment: Yes, I am happy with your answer, +1. Technically, "going the other way around" is just reversing the steps! But I am $70%$ through my answer, so let me post that, to make things clear.

Comment: Yes, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: I just completed it.

Answer (score 4):

Let $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ be given. The defining series of $\exp(z)$ and $\exp(w)$ are both absolutely convergent, this means that their Cauchy-product converges to the product of their limit, i.e.:
\begin{align}
\exp(z)\exp(w)
&=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^i}{i!}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{w^j}{j!}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{i} \frac{z^k}{k!}\frac{w^{i-k}}{(i-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{i} z^k w^{i-k} \frac{1}{k! (i-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{i!}\sum_{k=0}^{i} z^k w^{i-k} \frac{i!}{k! (i-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(z+w)^i}{i!}\\
&=\exp(z+w)
\end{align}

Comment: Very elegant solution my friend!

Comment: Thank you, @whitenoise :)

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of the exponential, you know that $f(x) = e^x$ verifies $f'(x) = f(x).$ Moreover it is clear that the solutions of this differential equation are all the $C e^x$ with $C$ a constant. Now, for fixed $w$, consider the function $f_w : z \mapsto e^{z+w}.$ One has, $$f_w'(z) = e^{z+w} = f_w(z).$$ Hence $$f_w(z) = C e^{z}$$ for some $C$. By evaluating at $z=0$, you will find $C=e^w$ and get the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing $e^{z}=1+z+z^2/2!+\cdots$ and $e^{w}=1+w+w^2/2!+\cdots,$
we have 
 $e^{z}.e^{w}=(1+z+z^2/2!+......) (1+w+w^2/2!+......)=1+(z+w)+(z^2+w^2+2zw)/2!+.......=1+(z+w)+(z+w)^2/2!+.......=e^{z+w}.$
Check the other few terms.

Comment: In your expansion of $e^z\cdot e^w$ you show an expansion of $e^z\cdot e^z$

Comment: I proved it this way but I can't seem to prove it doing it "backwards"